# submetries on Riemannian manifolds independent radius

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Problem: Let $S:M\rightarrow N$ be a submetry between connected Riemannian manifolds. So $S(B(p,r))=B(S(p),r)$ for all $p$ and $r>0$. Then, we know that for every $n\in N$, there exists some $r(n)>0$ such that for any $s\leq r$, $\overline{B}_{s}(n)$ is strictly convex in $N$.
Now, I was wondering if, say, $N$ is compact (or $M$ or both) then can we find an $R>0$ such that for every $n$ and every $R'<R$, $\overline{B}(n,R')$ is strictly convex in $N$.

That is, can we take the radius independent of the points when compactness involved? It seems to me yeah but not sure how. I'd like a purely metric proof if possible

Comment: What is a submetry? I thought I could guess, but then your second sentence — with an equality — would not follow.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's the standard definition of a Submetry. Balls are preserved in the sense of my second sentence

Comment: Your question is just about $N$ and is independent of $S$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Sure. Yeah